# Mac OS X open context under focus not cursor

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, focus

I am really used to the **Shift**+**F10** shortcut from Windows. For example I got folder selected by arrow keys in Explorer, then I press **Shift**+**F10** and can do some stuff without touching the mouse.

Under Mac OS X this shortcut open dialog under my cursor but not focused element. How can I make Mac OS X open dialog under focused element?

Comment: Pressing Shift+F10 on my mac doesn't do a thing but I think this should help you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32715/how-do-i-open-the-context-menu-from-a-mac-keyboard Usually there is a direct shortcut for all the functionality in the context menu. If not but it is in the menubar, you can make your own shortcut in "System Preferences » Keyboard"

Comment: I am used to get context menu open, then see all options and pick one. In best case it can be invoked by some letter (for example 'Show history' by 'h' which is underlined). It is really good feature of MS Windows that improves my user-experience alot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct alternative I could think of but there is a very helpful function which is usable in almost every application (except some Adobe products *sic!*). You can search through the menu options:

[image: search menubar entries]

You can invoke this search field by pressing `Command+Shift+/`. This not only shows you where to find the menu entry but also possible shortcuts. You can still assign custom shortcuts for unbound and already bound entries with the Keyboard system preference pane. You can also press enter when an item is selected.